# Is it possible to play 2 of a kind or 3 of a kind while I'm blinded by the Curse of the Cat Butt?

Tags: exploding-kittens

[Curse of the cat butt](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/streaking-kittens) from the Streaking Kitten extension blinds me and I have to randomly play cards until I draw a card successfully (unless it's an exploding kitten and I need to defuse it blindly). I know the rules when someone tries to steal from me while I'm blinded, but what happens if I want to use a special combination while blinded? Can I simply play all my cards for a special combination and discard all cards that don't add to a 2 of a kind or 3 of a kind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When playing blind, you can only play one card at a time.

Curse of the Cat Butt is a clone/replacement of Blind as a Bat and follows the same rules.

[Blind as a Bat instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eto2N.jpg):

> any cards must be played blind (pick one blindly, and place it face up on the Discard pile).

The expression of the Curse of the Cat Butt rules/instructions tried to clarify some points but ended up with this one point muddled. It's still kinda in there, though:

> On their turn, if the blind player decides to play any cards, those cards must be picked randomly and played face up on the Discard Pile. If **the card** is playable, play as normal.

The way to reconcile the shift from plural to singular is to read it like Blind as a Bat:

Cards are played to the discard pile, and each time, if the card (singular) is playable, ...

Comment: Thanks Scott! I know this is a bit tricky as it is not 100% definite in the streaking kitten rules, but thanks to your knowledge about the Blind as a Bat card this was finally resolved :)

Comment: What is the name of the extension that includes Blind as a Bat?

Comment: It was in "Hidden Compartment" https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/232697/hidden-compartment-pack-expansion-cards-against-hu